# How to know which segue was used using Swift?

Tags: swift, segue

I have a main viewController and a detailsViewController. The detailsViewController has 2 buttons. Both buttons are segues back to the main controller but I want to customize the main viewController based on which segue was used. What is the best way to check which segue was used to reach a viewController so that the main viewController can be customized depending on that? - if segue1 leads to the the main viewController then I want label1 hidden. if segue2 leads to the main viewController, then I want label2 hidden.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Main View Controller create a variable , something like

```
var vcOne : Bool = true
```

Now in DetailsViewController

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue_one"
        {
            let mainVC : MainViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MainViewController
            secondVC.vcOne = true


        }
        else if segue.identifier == "segue_two"
        {
           let mainVC : MainViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MainViewController
            secondVC.vcOne = false
        }

    }
```

Now in MainView Controller

```
     override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
             super.viewWillAppear(animated)

             //Now check here for which segue
            if(vcOne)
           {
            // implement for button one click

            }
           else
           {
              // implement for button two click 

           }


        }
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like to check which segue was used. You have to set an identifier to the segue in the storyboard though!

```
    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier" {
        let yourVC = segue.destinationViewController as? yourViewController
        //do magic with your destination
    }
}
```

Comment: I have that to send data to the mainViewController but what I want is to implement something in the mainViewController that checks which segue was used to get back to the main view controller, and depending on that...doing something with the main viewController

Answer (score 0):

There is a option for setting Identifier for segue. This should be unique identifier. So that you can identify which segue is activated.
Ex:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Identifier1" {
        let firstVC = segue.destinationViewController as? FirstViewController

    } else if segue.identifier == "Identifier2" {
        let secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController

    }
}
```